# pickle.load give memory address in python instead of values

Tags: python, theano, pickle, lasagne

I am trying to load data from pickle file but it returned me memory address instead of values. Is there any solution?

```
    import numpy as np
    import cPickle
    import lasagne
    import theano
    import theano.tensor as T
       fa=open('fahad.pkl', 'rb') 
       c=cPickle.load(fa)
       print(c)

      (<network.Network object at 0x00000000BFC8E908>, <network.Network 
      object at 0x00000000665C93C8>, <network.Network object at 
      0x00000000C014B630>)
```

Network is another python file in same folder.

Comment: can u try iterating the code    **for objects in data:  
    for thing in objects:    
        print(thing[0]*thing[1]),  
    print("") **

Comment: I have download this pickle file and do not know any of its contents yet. how to iterate then?

Comment: try this code and this should show out the data

Comment: i am new to python. Can you post script here for what you are saying? I am getting error.